# Can't Programmatically Open Mac Menu Bar NSPopover View

Tags: swift, macos, nspopover

I’m working on a Mac menu bar application and have this working code that opens/closes the window when toggling the menu bar app icon

```
@objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let button = statusBarItem.button {
      if popover.isShown {
        popover.performClose(sender)
      } else {
        popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
      }
    }
  }
```

I’m trying to add this function that will programmatically open the window after the user has logged in (which occurs via a web view)

```
func openPopover() {
    if let button = statusBarItem.button {
      if !popover.isShown {
        popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
      }
    }
  }
```

The `popopver.show` code gets executed, but, the popover never appears. Can’t see that I’m doing any obviously wrong things here. Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Actually just calling `togglePopover` should do the job.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Then you call `show` probably too soon in terms of view life cycle.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.